# Modal Reset and Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my Modal layout:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myContact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Send me a message</h3>
    <div id="thanks"></div>
</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="contact" name="contact">

        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name"><br>

        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your E-mail"><br>


        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Message"></textarea>

    </form>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">Nah.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery Script:

```
 $("input#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php", //process to mail
        data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#myContact").modal('hide'); //hide popup 
            $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you  



        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

And the PHP process.php:

```
<?php
//add the recipient's address here
$myemail = 'test@mail.com';

//grab named inputs from html then post to #thanks
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
echo "<class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been !";

//generate email and send!
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

First of all, Hello to  All i`m new here.... 
I have a question.. how can I do when i push Send my Modal to hide (but whit delay to see the alert-success message  ) and to be reset...

now  is working and send my email but does not close and reset..

Thx Elod !!

Comment: just for confirmation, do you want the modal to close and reset correct?

Comment: Sorry for my english,  Yes that's what i want (and maybe to hide whit delay // echo "<class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been !"; //) And the Modal close whit delay to because success alert is echo in the modal. Thx

Answer (score 0):

on success you can use `reset` to reset the form in the modal

use an `id` for the form like `my_Contact`

```
$('#my_contact').reset(); //to reset the form
```

delay the modal hide can use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#myContact').modal('hide'); }, 3000);
```

Comment: All this I tried but i dont know whay they are not working... What i have in success is not working.. now i realize the send messasge php is doing not the JS

Comment: in ajax success alert the message you sent, then if you got the message.

Comment: check the message is not empty or not, then hide and reset the model.One more thing in the response from `process.php` just add some tag name before the `class`.

Comment: Now i see this form is for Bootstrap v2.3.1 and my page is loding Bootstrap 3.. and for this is not working properly.. and if i copy  Bootstrap v2 all my page is messed up, i must look for form with ajax activation bootstrap V3